# How my character stays near a block?

Tags: graphics, geometry, collision-detection

I have a problem with block/wall detection:

[image]

red = character

green = block/wall

Attempt: When my character touches e.g. a block/wall on the left side it should stay on the left side.

```
int len = blocks.size();

for (int b = 0; b < len; b++) {

  Block block = block.get(i);

  Rectangle r1 = red.bounds;
  Rectangle r2 = block.bounds;

  if((r1.lowerLeft.y + r1.height/2) > (r2.lowerLeft.y - r2.height/2)) {
   ...
  }

  if((r1.lowerLeft.y - r1.height/2) < (r2.lowerLeft.y + r2.height/2)) {
   ...
  }

  if((r1.lowerLeft.x + r1.width/2) > (r2.lowerLeft.x - r2.width/2)) {
   ...
  }

  if((r1.lowerLeft.x - r1.width/2) < (r2.lowerLeft.x + r2.width/2)) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you just had to mingle the code.
Your condition to find out if its on the top then computes what had to be done if it was on the bottom. Just exchange the code inside the conditions and you're good to go, i guess!